# ObjectAnimator repeat loop delay

Tags: java, android, animator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="rotationX"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-360"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"> 
</objectAnimator>
```

This is my object animator xml

```
 //Animating the NormalLayout
   final ObjectAnimator anim4 = (ObjectAnimator) //Object animator
   AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.rotate_four);
//And this is my java code
```

I want to add delay between its looping, like 3 secs between looping again. I have tried animation listeners `onRepeat`, `onEnd` kinda stuff but it didn't worked. I want some delay between looping.

Any help would be appreciated to its utmost limit.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before you ask a question. Just ask what you want, no chit-chat!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try 
1.delete the xml property `android:repeatCount="infinite"`
2.add the java code

```
anim4.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                anim4.start();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I find it better to change the DelayedAnimationRepeater to not re-start the animation and thus allow for .setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE) and onAnimationRepeat to be called as one would expect.

So simply changing it to

```
public class DelayedAnimationRepeater implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private long delayMillis;

    public DelayedAnimationRepeater(long delayMillis) {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animator) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        animator.pause();
        new Handler().postDelayed(animator::resume, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

results in a much better experience imho. Now you can truly repeat your animation and listen in on the onAnimationRepeat event.

Answer (score 1):

**Helper class**:

```
public class DelayedAnimationRepeater implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private long delayMillis;

    public DelayedAnimationRepeater(long delayMillis) {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animator) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Start delay should only affect initial start, not repeats
                animator.setStartDelay(0);
                animator.start();
            }
        }, delayMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
anim4.addListener(new DelayedAnimationRepeater(3000));
```